# How to get attribute of element loaded from plugin like lightbox

Tags: java, selenium, lightbox

i'm trying to get an attribue of an image loaded by clicking on an href. I see that when i click on the link, it load at the top of body a div with all element inside.

So What i try is:

```
js.executeScript("showModal(1,2,'"+nv+"',0);");
WebElement im =(new WebDriverWait(d, 10))
.until(new ExpectedCondition<WebElement>(){
@Override
   public WebElement apply(WebDriver d) {
      return d.findElement(By.id("imgView"));
   }});

System.out.println(im.findElement(By.tagName("img")).getAttribute("src"));
```

but i retrieve:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 10 seconds waiting for mm.Main$2@741827d1
Build info: version: '2.21.0', revision: '16552', time: '2012-04-11 19:08:38'
System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.8', java.version: '1.6.0_33'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.timeoutException(FluentWait.java:252)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:221)
    at mm.Main.main(Main.java:85)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"imgView"}
Command duration or timeout: 43 milliseconds
```

the function `showModal` let to lightbox to happer and load the image inside it.

how can i solve? can someone help me? thanks!!

Comment: 1. Try using PageSource method of webdriver to find if the its available or not. And do this after a Thread.sleep of 2-3 seconds. 2. Sometimes xpath work and not other things. So, try all possible means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking at your stacktrace:

Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"imgView"}

Selenium is executing your code fine it just can't find your element with the id=imgView in the html. Finding elements by id is usually much quicker than by pure xpath or css locators, but I've had experiences where they break for some reason and then I have to use xpath or css.

Try looking for your element by a css locator: I obviously can't see your html source, but if you're unfamiliar with programming css locators try this: http://sauceio.com/index.php/2010/01/selenium-totw-css-selectors-in-selenium-demystified/

If css doesnt work then go by xpath...although this is generally not recommended by the community sometimes I have no choice when running my tests.

This can give you a breakdown of the pros and cons of each type of locator http://marakana.com/bookshelf/selenium_tutorial/locators.html and also some helpful examples as well.